# Alamofire build fails with 138 errors

Tags: alamofire

I just imported Alamofire into a Swift project (via cocoapods) and my build fails because of Alamofire. XCode says there are 138 errors in Alamofire.

Here is a pick of just one error (given in the Alamofire.swift file).
value of optional type String not unwrapped :

```
extension NSURL: URLStringConvertible {

    public var URLString: String {

        return absoluteString // error shows here

    }

}
```

Most errors are "swift compiler errors"

I have tried the following :

- closing and reopening XCode
- pod remove repo master / pod setup / pod install
- rm -rf MyProject.xcworkspace / pod install

but no success so far.

I am running the latest cocoapods pre-release (0.39.0.beta.4) and XCode 6.4

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please provide the following information:

- Which version of Xcode are you using? 
- Which version of cocoapods are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are using Xcode 6.4, which uses Swift 1.2

Since the master branch of Alamofire now uses Swift 2.0 you'll need to update to Xcode 7

Alternatively you can supply the version '1.3.1' in your podfile, as this was the last version using Swift 1.2.

Comment: OK. I will try that. But I do find it weird that I have to use a beta version of XCode to use a dependency. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit difficult at the moment as Swift changes quite quickly. Xcode 7 is a GM though, so it will probably be released with the same build number. Please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

In Pod file insert Below code....It works for me.

xcode version should be 7.3+
swift should be 2.2  (In preferences-> location-> select command line tool-> xcode 7.3).

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.3'
use_frameworks!

target 'Your Target Name' do
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end
```

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Swift2.0 but i used Alamofire 1.2.2 which caused compiler problems. After i switched to Alamofire 2.0 in the Pod Files, everything worked fine.

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 2.0'
```